# Android app crash when press home and send app to background

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am new to android, and is writing a simple game using surfaceview and thread, but now when I press home button, app will crash,below is the crash log. Could someone have any idea about this?

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 2474K, 49% free 14273K/27939K, paused 20ms+41ms
06-18 22:09:51.672    1730-1730/?                              D/skia: Decode special JPEG file
06-18 22:09:51.692    1447-5519/?                              W/memalloc: /dev/pmem: No more pmem available
06-18 22:09:51.692    1447-5519/?                              W/memalloc: Falling back to ashmem
06-18 22:09:51.712    1447-5519/?                              D/memalloc: ashmem: Allocated buffer base:0x440f1000 size:1536000 fd:63
06-18 22:09:51.722    1730-1730/?                              D/memalloc: ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5743f000 size:1536000 fd:94
06-18 22:09:51.792   1447-13308/?                              W/memalloc: /dev/pmem: No more pmem available
06-18 22:09:51.792   1447-13308/?                              W/memalloc: Falling back to ashmem
06-18 22:09:51.802   1447-13308/?                              D/memalloc: ashmem: Allocated buffer base:0x442bf000 size:1536000 fd:71
06-18 22:09:51.802    1730-1730/?                              D/memalloc: ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x575b6000 size:1536000 fd:102
06-18 22:09:51.912  27744-27744/com.example.gametestproject    D/memalloc: /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52fbb000 size:16502784 offset:15732736
06-18 22:09:51.912  27744-27744/com.example.gametestproject    D/memalloc: /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52708000 size:6914048 offset:6144000
06-18 22:09:51.922    1447-1447/?                              E/SurfaceTexture: [SurfaceView] disconnect: connected to another api (cur=0, req=2)
06-18 22:09:51.922  27744-27744/com.example.gametestproject    A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=128)
06-18 22:09:52.002  27744-27926/com.example.gametestproject    A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=128)
06-18 22:09:52.213  26689-26713/?                              D/ConnCtl: Dormancy countdown sec:10
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: debuggerd: 2013-06-18 22:09:52
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'htccn_chs_cmcc/htc_primotd/primotd:4.0.3/IML74K/61230.1:user/release-keys'
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: pid: 27744, tid: 27744  >>> com.example.gametestproject <<<
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 128 (?), fault addr 00000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: r0 ffffffff  r1 bfbf8453  r2 00c85358  r3 00ccdac0
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: r4 ffffffff  r5 bfbf8453  r6 00cbaa78  r7 00cbaa78
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: r8 bee35598  r9 00000000  10 4d384466  fp bee355d4
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: ip 400cc160  sp bee35518  lr 400d6164  pc 400d6164  cpsr 08000010
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d0  3a74657366666f36  d1  2072656666756231
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d2  0000000400000334  d3  5197b09800000034
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d4  00bda3500000017f  d5  ffffffff00b9cef8
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d6  0000000b00000001  d7  0000000000750053
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d16 000000c240ab8fe8  d17 3ff0000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d18 0018001700160014  d19 001a0018001a0019
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d20 0000000000000000  d21 3ff0000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d22 4032000000000000  d23 3ff0000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d24 0022002000220021  d25 0026002500240023
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d28 0000000000000000  d29 3ff0000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: d30 0026002600260026  d31 0000000000000000
06-18 22:09:52.333  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: scr 80000013
06-18 22:09:52.763  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #00  pc 00005164  /system/lib/libcutils.so (android_atomic_add)
06-18 22:09:52.763  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #01  pc 0001b31c  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #02  pc 00022e9a  /system/lib/libgui.so (_ZN7android20SurfaceTextureClientD2Ev)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #03  pc 00025b78  /system/lib/libgui.so (_ZN7android7SurfaceD1Ev)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #04  pc 00025b8c  /system/lib/libgui.so (_ZN7android7SurfaceD0Ev)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #05  pc 0001b338  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #06  pc 0005dce2  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #07  pc 0005de22  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #08  pc 0001eeb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #09  pc 0005958c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
06-18 22:09:52.773  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: code around pc:
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: 400d6144 e1853f92 e3530000 1afffffa e8bd8070  .?....S.....p...
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: 400d6154 e92d4070 e1a04000 e1a05001 ebffffd4  p@-..@...P......
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: 400d6164 e1950f9f e0802004 e1853f92 e3530000  ..... ...?....S.
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: 400d6174 1afffffa e8bd8070 e1a01000 e3e00000  ....p...........
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: 400d6184 eafffff2 e1a01000 e3a00001 eaffffef  ................
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: stack:
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354d8  00cadae0  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354dc  40063558
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354e0  00000080
06-18 22:09:52.783  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354e4  400634b4
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354e8  00cadae8  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354ec  00000000
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354f0  4d384466  /system/framework/framework.odex
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354f4  40030c51  /system/lib/libc.so
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354f8  00cadae8  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee354fc  407ea3b4  /system/lib/libgui.so
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35500  00cbab30  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35504  00cbab30  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35508  bee35598  [stack]
06-18 22:09:52.793  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee3550c  00000000
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35510  df0027ad
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35514  00000000
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #00 bee35518  bfbf8453
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee3551c  41acdac0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35520  00cbaa78  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35524  400b731f  /system/lib/libutils.so
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: #01 bee35528  00cbaa08  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee3552c  407ea3b4  /system/lib/libgui.so
06-18 22:09:52.803  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35530  00cbaa78  [heap]
06-18 22:09:52.803    1616-1628/?                              W/CpuWake: >>releaseCpuPerfWakeLock
06-18 22:09:52.803    1616-1628/?                              W/CpuWake: <<releaseCpuPerfWakeLock
06-18 22:09:52.813  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: bee35534  407d9e9d  /system/lib/libgui.so
06-18 22:09:53.224  26689-26713/?                              D/ConnCtl: Dormancy countdown sec:9
06-18 22:09:53.844  27572-27572/?                              I/DEBUG: debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
06-18 22:09:53.844    1616-1634/?                              I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-18 22:09:53.874  28099-28099/?                              I/DEBUG: debuggerd: May  4 2012 00:26:47
```

Comment: Are you using the NDK?